# Systemd socket: listendatagram vs listenstream

Tags: systemd, socket

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY9GYsoxeLg) very nice presentation of `systemd` the first speaker presents two cases of socket-based service activation.

The first unit file corresponds to a `tftp` socket and it is the following

`tftp.socket`

```
[Unit]
Tftp server activation socket

[Socket]
ListenDatagram=69

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

The second is the example of the also socket-activated `cockpit` service on RHEL7

`cockpit.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=Cockpit Web Server Socket
Documentation=man:cockpit-ws(8)

[Socket]
ListenStream=9090

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

I assume that both values of `ListenDatagram` and `ListenStream` refer to the port each corresponding service will be activated by, what is the purpose of these 2 different namings?

Comment: See post about [difference between stream and datagram sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953912/difference-between-unix-domain-stream-and-datagram-sockets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [systemd.socket](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#ListenStream=) man page. For internet sockets a simple number is indeed a port number and the difference between them is that datagram means udp and stream means tcp.

However, these options can also take values like `/my/file`, when they refer to Unix domain sockets, and the difference is as given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953912/difference-between-unix-domain-stream-and-datagram-sockets) by Marko Kosmerl, namely whether a reader can see the boundaries between packets from a writer or not.